# MetalKit's drawInMTKView function not called if app is built using cmake/make?

Tags: c++, cmake, metal, metalkit

I ran into a strange issue testing [Metal cpp](https://developer.apple.com/metal/cpp/). The following project is almost the same as [Apple's official Metal Cpp example project](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10160/).

https://github.com/shi-yan/testmetal

The apple official example contains an Xcode project, whereas my modified version tries to use cmake.

My cmake project builds and runs, but the window is empty. I debugged it, the root cause is that the drawInMTKView function never gets called.

If I generate an Xcode project using cmake, then build and run my code in Xcode, the resulting app can render to its window just fine.

However, if I run the same app binary through the terminal, it will show an empty window again.

Any idea what might cause this? Thanks.

Comment: Try changing `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice` to `MTLCopyAllDevices()` and get the first device.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to an Apple engineer, [the issue is resolved](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711647).

My CMakeLists.txt doesn't load MetalKit. XCode can load MetalKit automatically, hence there was no issue running it via xcode.

Adding MetalKit to my CMakeList.txt solved the issue.

Comment: Yeah, this works because `View debugging` diagnostics option in scheme settings just inserts CoreAnimation, Metal and a lot of AppKit by default. I guess cmake generated projects don't have that.